# What would be a good option to explain a ratio is this and that

Tags: phrase-choice

Here I am trying to say a ratio as in 1 and 2.

What would be a good option to explain a ratio is this and that - either 1 or 2

> 1. The ratio *of minimum rectangle’s floor area to enclosed circle area*
>      is tested with a defined threshold and a candidate, given a low ratio,
>      is taken as natural object assuming that natural object has a more
>      irregular boundary.
> 2. The ratio *between floor area of enclosed minimum rectangle and
>      enclosed circle area* is tested with a defined threshold and a
>      candidate, given a low ratio, is taken as natural object assuming that
>      natural object has a more irregular boundary.

Comment: The first sentence is correct. For example: 3/4 is the ratio of 3 to 4. Not sure about the second sentence, but it doesn't sound right  to me. When I think "between" in this context, I think of "difference", not "ratio". But I may be wrong here.

Comment: I'm sorry to report that while the first sentence may use *"The ratio **of** "* correctly, apart from that it is gibberish.

Comment: The first half of each example (the part about the ratio) duplicates a previous question; the second part, “is taken as natural object assuming that natural object has a more irregular boundary” makes no sense.